# task scheduler not executing batch file properly

Tags: powershell, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

when I am running  a batch file in windows task scheduler It is not giving correct output and show error for copying 2 .bak files , but if I run it as power shell  file it give accurate output and no error occurs.this code is copying backup folder from production and copying it to backup server. backup folder has 2 subfolders db and blobs .in db folder there are 3 .bak files (It is nexus repo backup).This is how  I converted it into batch file

```
cd C:\script
powershell.exe -file C:\code\backup_script.ps1
```

here is the powershell file

```
    function CheckInDir {

        if (!(Test-Path $BackupDir)) {
            return $false
            Logging "Error" "$BackupDir does not exist"
        }
        if (!(Test-Path $Destination)) {
            return $false
            Logging "Error" "$Destination does not exist"
        }
    }

    filter Test-DirectoryEmpty($directory) {
        #[bool](Get-ChildItem $directory\* -Force)
        [bool](Test-Path $directory)
    }
    Function Restore-Backup {
        Logging "INFO" "Started the Restoring Backup..."
        if(!(Test-DirectoryEmpty $BackupDir)){
            Logging "Error" "$BackupDir is EMPTY!"
            return $false
        }

        $Folders = Get-ChildItem $BackupDir -Directory
        
        [hashtable]$DateTimeHashTable = [ordered]@{}

        $DatesValuesTable = @()
        foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {
            Logging "FOLDER" $Folder
            $FolderStringLen = ($Folder | measure-object -character | Select-Object -expandproperty characters)
            $FolderTimestamp = $Folder.Name.Substring(12, $FolderStringLen-12)
            Logging "FILE TIMESTAMP" $FolderTimestamp
            
            [datetime]$newFolderDateTime = [datetime]::ParseExact($FolderTimestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss', $null)
            Logging "DATE" $newFolderDateTime

            # Add blob-backup datetime and string into HashTable
            $DateTimeHashTable.Add($newFolderDateTime, $Folder)
            #Logging "HASHTABLE VALUES" $DateTimeHashTable.Values

          
            $SortedDTHT = $DateTimeHashTable.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Value -Descending

           
            $DatesValuesTable = $SortedDTHT | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
          
        }   
        
    }

    Function CopyElementsInSingleBlobBackup($Folder){

        # Going into single Blob-Backup folder, 
        $BlobSubfolders = Get-ChildItem ${BackupDir}\${Folder} -Directory
        foreach ($BlobSubfolder in $BlobSubfolders) {
            Logging "_FOLDER" $BlobSubfolder

            # if it is subfolder "db", then files are being copied to $data-dir/restore-from-backup
            if ($BlobSubfolder -match 'db') {

                $BlobSubFiles = Get-ChildItem ${BackupDir}\${Folder}\${BlobSubfolder} -Recurse
                Logging "_._FILES" $BlobSubFiles
                
                foreach ($File in $BlobSubFiles) {
                    Logging "FILE ${File} is written FROM" "${BackupDir}\${Folder}\${BlobSubfolder}\${File}"
                    Logging "FILE ${File} is written TO" "${Destination}\restore-from-backup\${File}"
                    Copy-Item "${BackupDir}\${Folder}\${BlobSubfolder}\${File}" -Destination "${Destination}\restore-from-backup\${File}"
                }
            } else {
                # if folders are named "default" and "TEST", copy elements inside those folder to Destination\blobs subfolder
                Logging "FOLDER COPY FROM" "${BackupDir}\${Folder}\${BlobSubfolder}"
                Logging "FOLDER COPY TO" "${Destination}\blobs"
                Copy-Item "${BackupDir}\${Folder}\${BlobSubfolder}" -Destination "${Destination}\blobs" -Recurse
            }
        }
    }
Function Remove-db_folders {
    $data = @('component','config','security')
    $data | ForEach-Object {Remove-db_folder($PSItem)}
}

Function Remove-db_folder {
    param ($FolderItem)
    $thisFolder = "${Destination}\db\${FolderItem}"
    if(Test-DirectoryEmpty $thisFolder){
        Logging "INFO" "Removing folder ${thisFolder}"
        Remove-Item $thisFolder -Recurse
    }
}


Function CheckNexusServiceStatus($nexusServ) {
    $nexusServiceStatus = $nexusServ.Status
    Logging "INFO" "Nexus service status is ${nexusServiceStatus}"
}
$CheckDir=CheckInDir #returns true or false

if ($CheckDir -eq $false) {
    Logging "ERROR" "One of the Directory are not available, Script has stopped"
} else {

    Stop-Service -Name "nexus"
    $nexusService = Get-Service -Name 'nexus'
    CheckNexusServiceStatus($nexusService)

    if ($nexusService.Status -eq 'Stopped') {

        Remove-db_folders

        Restore-Backup
```

If I run it as power shell it is working properly but while running in task scheduler as batch file it gives the error

```
Get-childItem: cannot find path 'C:\nexus\blob-backup\db\c:\nexus\blob-backup\db' because it does not exist.
at C:\script.ps1 146 char:5
Get-ChildItem "˘{BackupDir}\${Folder}\${BlobSubfolder}\...."
+CategoryInfo   : objectNotfound
+FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.power.shell.commands.GetchildItem
```

can any one help me to figure out why this error only occur in task scheduler?

Comment: Change `"${BackupDir}\${Folder}\${BlobSubfolder}"` to `$BlobSubfolder.FullName`

Comment: Your filter `Test-DirectoryEmpty` only checks if a file or folder exists. it does NOT check if it is empty or not.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen by replacing it to `$BlobSubfolder.FullName` it enters in some kind of infinite loop